# Javascript animate content In and hide

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to animate whole bunch of cards in with javascript and hide them when they press a button a data filter. what would be the best way in doing this?

I was thinking of using hide() and show() but zooms the content out and looks bad, I would like to do more of a sorting fade in and out but want to clear the grid and fade items in nicely.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/js/foundation.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button-group">
    <button class="button category-button" data-filter="all" type="button">
        All
    </button>
    <button class="button category-button" data-filter="attraction" type="button">
        attraction
    </button>
    <button class="button category-button" data-filter="bar-pub" type="button">
        bar-pub
    </button>
    <button class="button category-button" data-filter="theater" type="button">
        theater
    </button>
</div>


<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x small-up-2 medium-up-3">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="assets/img/generic/rectangle-1.jpg">
        <div class="card-section">
        <h4>This is a row of cards.</h4>
          <p>This row of cards is embedded in an X-Y Block Grid.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="assets/img/generic/rectangle-1.jpg">
        <div class="card-section">
          <h4>This is a card.</h4>
          <p>It has an easy to override visual style, and is appropriately subdued.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">
        <img src="assets/img/generic/rectangle-1.jpg">
        <div class="card-section">
          <h4>This is a card.</h4>
          <p>It has an easy to override visual style, and is appropriately subdued.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have `hide` and `show` methods. If you're using jQuery it should be in your tags. Your question is a bit broad. Normally you're required to try something and ask about your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're after?

This assumes each card is a `type` of category like your filter buttons.

Notice the new `data-type` added to the cards and the typo on `theatre`.

To achieve the fade effect, we use jQuery's `fadeOut()` and `fadeIn()` methods. You can view more information about [jQuery effects here](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_effects.asp).

```js
//when a button is clicked
$('.button-group button').on('click', function(){

  //store the category of the clicked button
  var category = $(this).attr('data-filter');
  
  //Loop through all `.card` elements
  $('.card').each(function(){
    
    //If the current card in this loop has the same category as the button and it's not the 'all' button then hide it, otherwise fade all cards back in.
    if($(this).attr('data-type') != category && category != 'all') {
      $(this).fadeOut();
    } else {
      $(this).fadeIn()
    }
   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/js/foundation.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="button-group">
    <button class="button category-button" data-filter="all" type="button">
        All
    </button>
    <button class="button category-button" data-filter="attraction" type="button">
        attraction
    </button>
    <button class="button category-button" data-filter="bar-pub" type="button">
        bar-pub
    </button>
    <button class="button category-button" data-filter="theatre" type="button">
        theater
    </button>
</div>


<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x small-up-2 medium-up-3">
    <div class="cell">
      <div data-type="bar-pub" class="card">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
        <div class="card-section">
        <h4>I'm the bar/pub type</h4>
          <p>This row of cards is embedded in an X-Y Block Grid.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div data-type="attraction" class="card">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
        <div class="card-section">
          <h4>I'm the attraction type</h4>
          <p>It has an easy to override visual style, and is appropriately subdued.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div data-type="theatre" class="card">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
        <div class="card-section">
          <h4>I'm the theatre type</h4>
          <p>It has an easy to override visual style, and is appropriately subdued.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll wanna apply the data attributes set on your buttons to the corresponding card and from there just query the card based on its' value:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.category-button').on('click', function() {
    const filter = this.dataset.filter;
    const $filteredCard = $(`.card[data-filter="${filter}"]`);
    
    if (filter === 'all') {
      $('.card').stop().fadeIn();
    } else {
      $filteredCard.stop().fadeIn();
      
      $('.card').not($filteredCard).stop().fadeOut();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/foundation/6.4.3/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="button-group">
  <button class="button category-button" data-filter="all" type="button">
        All
    </button>
  <button class="button category-button" data-filter="attraction" type="button">
        attraction
    </button>
  <button class="button category-button" data-filter="bar-pub" type="button">
        bar-pub
    </button>
  <button class="button category-button" data-filter="theater" type="button">
        theater
    </button>
</div>


<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x grid-padding-x small-up-2 medium-up-3">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card" data-filter="attraction">
        <img src="assets/img/generic/rectangle-1.jpg">
        <div class="card-section">
          <h4>This is a row of cards.</h4>
          <p>This row of cards is embedded in an X-Y Block Grid.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card" data-filter="bar-pub">
        <img src="assets/img/generic/rectangle-1.jpg">
        <div class="card-section">
          <h4>This is a card.</h4>
          <p>It has an easy to override visual style, and is appropriately subdued.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card" data-filter="theater">
        <img src="assets/img/generic/rectangle-1.jpg">
        <div class="card-section">
          <h4>This is a card.</h4>
          <p>It has an easy to override visual style, and is appropriately subdued.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```